# What's wrong with my post?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, asking-questions

I'm sorry that this might be a duplicate question. I've checked out many posts on meta, but it seems that none of them suits my situation. If it's duplicate, please close it.

Here's my question: I asked a question few days ago: [How to find such an isotropic space](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2319347/how-to-find-such-an-isotropic-space)?,  but there's no response at all, with no comments and no answers. So I guessed that there's something wrong with my post. Hence, I searched on meta and thought that I might be  not explicit enough with my efforts. Therefore, I edited my question and expanded my attempts. However, even though there's more people visited my post and someone upvoted for it, there's still no comments and no hints.

I'm not sure what have I done wrong. Maybe I didn't ask well. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: I've added a bounty to your question. Maybe that will help.

Comment: @user49640 Thanks a lot! It's really nice of you.

Comment: My pleasure. Until they make it where you can exchange reputation points for Bitcoin, there's not much else I can do with them.

Comment: @user49640 feature request pls? I'd spend too much time on M.SE if that was the case ;)

Comment: The main thing wrong is unusual terminology. What book are you using?